# Find leftest duplicate of binary search result

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

Say I have an ordered array with lots of duplicates:

```
var array = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
              2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
              3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
              4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
              5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ];
```

I also have code to perform a binary search for the index of the closest value within a sorted array:

```
function binaryClosestIndexOf(array, value) {
  var mid,
    lo = 0,
    hi = array.length - 1;

  while (hi - lo > 1) {
    mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;

    if (array[mid] > value)
      hi = mid;
    else
      lo = mid;
  }

  if (value - array[lo] <= array[hi] - value)
    return lo;
  else 
    return hi;
}
```

Performing a few example searches unveils my issue:

```
binaryClosestIndexOf(array, 3.5);
> 14 // array[14] = 3
binaryClosestIndexOf(array, 3.50001);
> 15 // array[15] = 4
binaryClosestIndexOf(array, 3.9);
> 15 // array[15] = 4
binaryClosestIndexOf(array, 4);
> 19 // array[19] = 4
binaryClosestIndexOf(array, 4.49999);
> 19 // array[19] = 4
```

As we can see, there is no issue with the algorithm, it does return the closest value. But it returns an interesting mixture of indices, from the leftest to the rightest.

**I want to get the leftest duplicate index**. I could introduce an **O(n)** search after the binary search, iterating through each value in the array after until a value is found that is smaller than the current value. I don't want to do this.

Is there a way to elegantly perform a binary search that will end up with the leftest duplicate value? Bonus points for an algorithm for the rightest value, too!

Comment: Where is `arr` defined?

Comment: The only thing you can do is to perform your binary search as it is and then to check if your target is smaller than the result. (target is 3.9 and you get 4) If so you already have the leftmost 4. However if not, that means you have got the rightmost one hence you have to iterate left up until you meet the last duplicate item.

Comment: @guest271314 Typo!

Comment: "I could introduce an O(n) search after the binary search, iterating through each value in the array after until a value is found that is smaller than the current value.", can I ask why `O(n)` when it is definitely `O(lg(n))`?

Comment: @user3707125 I meant to iterate incrementally sorry, I didn't think of doing a second binary search - that wasn't well written, i.e., if I found `array[i] = target`, then test `array[--i]` until found, which is `O(n)` (very worst case, mind you!).

Comment: If you want the leftmost match you must test for `if (array[mid] >= value)`

Comment: @stefan What if there are duplicate values? Testing is great, but I'd need to loop over values until I find one that is `array[index] > value`.

Comment: @NickBull you don't need second binary search you just need to add something like `for(step = currPos; step>0;step/=2) { if (array[currPos-step]==array[currPos]) currPos-=step; }` after your binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a binary search, if you search for an exact value, you are not promised any location (rightest or leftest), it could be in the middle.

Since binary search works by having a sorted list and reducing by factors of two finding an edge index could be difficult.

I can think of two approaches

1. use a loop afterwards, I think you could make that to be expected O(log(n)) using randomness as you could say the final loop would be expected constant time O(1).
2. Use a second binary search (once you know the value) for the index closest to that number minus 0.000001  (in your list 4 cases this would always result in the second run searching for 3.99999, which would yield 15.  Note: You should check in case the number (3.999999) was in the list and move right one place to get your value unless you can ensure a certain degree of rounding in the list.  This would be 2*log(n) or O(log(n)).

If your list is long, I think the expected run time for option 2 would actually be longer than option 1 because 2*log(n) would be > log(n) + a constant unless you know there will be lots of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.indexOf()`

```
return array.indexOf(array[value - array[lo] <= array[hi] - value ? lo : hi])
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this is supposed to be used?